# modifying a ConcurrentHashMap and Synchronized ArrayList in same method

Tags: java, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I have a collection of objects that is modified by one thread and read by another (more specifically the EDT). I needed a solution that gave me fast look up and also fast indexing (by order inserted), so I'm using a ConcurrentHashMap with an accompanying ArrayList of the keys, so if want to index an entry, I can index the List for the key and then use the returned key to get the value from the hash map. So I have a wrapper class that makes sure when and entry is added, the mapping is added to the hash map and the key is added to the list at the same time, similarly for removal.

I'm posting an example of the code in question:

```
private List<K> keys = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<K>(INITIAL_CAPACITY));

private ConcurrentMap<K, T> entries = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, T>(INITIAL_CAPACITY, .75f);

public synchronized T getEntryAt(int index){
     return entries.get(keys.get(index));
}

**public synchronized void addOrReplaceEntry(K key, T value){
     T result = entries.get(key);
     if(result == null){
         entries.putIfAbsent(key, value);
         keys.add(key);
     }
     else{
         entries.replace(key, result);
     }
}**

public syncrhonized T removeEntry(K key, T value){
     keys.remove(key);
     entries.remove(key, value);
}

public synchronized int getSize(){
     return keys.size();
}
```

my question is: am I losing all the benefits of using the ConcurrentHashMap (over syncrhonized hashmap) by operating on it in synchronized methods? I have to synchronize the methods to safely modify/read from the ArrayList of keys (CopyOnWriteArrayList is not an option because a lot of modification happens...) Also, if you know of a better way to do this, that would be appreciated...

Comment: It might not be a good idea to use a synchronized collection in the EDT size the constant synchronization done in the background might slow down the GUI.  (I'm not sure if it is something that is generally recommended to avoid... so comments from those who know better are welcomed.)

Comment: Also, using `keys.remove(key)` is `O(n)`, you lose all your *quick access by key* advantage.

Comment: While lockless soloutions are often desirable, most applications just use some form of synchronization to allow EDT and background threads to share data in a safe manner. Obviously long operations that block the data structure are not desirable, e.g. locking it and then iterating over each element doing some slow maths. In such cases copying the data is preferable.

Comment: @brain When you say "some form of synchronization" you mean using synchronized data type and not using SwingUtils.invokeLater?

Comment: remove happens very rarely...
one thread gets objects over a socket connection, adds them to the collection (or replaces if they exist)
a UI componenent uses the collection to display certain values (so for example get(index) is called on the edt.

Comment: @toto: using invokeLater() is a form of synchronization that could be used for mutating Models used in the EDT. As would using synchronized methods, synchronized blocks, explicit Lock objects and thread safe collections.

Comment: Would it be cleaner to have the worker thread (that is adding and replacing entries) to submit the modification of the collection to the EDT, so no synchronization/locking is needed? I generally try not to do something like this, but all these operations, barring delete, are pretty fast. so doing them on the EDT might actually perform better than calling synchronized methods on the EDT?

Comment: How does the read thread know what the correct index is?  The code to acquire an index and use it must be synchronized on the class in the example.  Otherwise a `remove` on the write thread between the acquire and the synch lock at the start of `getEntryAt` can make it wrong.  My gut feeling is that you want to rethink and and even get rid of your indexes.

Comment: @RalphChapin The indexes are important because a JTable's TableModel is using this collection to populate it's values. in a TableModel, getValueAt(index, column) is called A LOT, so the indexing performance is important. On the other hand, the socket is getting objects A LOT and needs to add them to the collection if they're new or replace them if they're there, to check if it's there on a list is O(n) and I'd like to improve that. that's why I have an array occompanying the hash map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using a Concurrent collection and a Synchronized collection in only synchronized blocks is a waste. You wont get the benefits of ConcurrentHashMap because only one thread will be accesing it at a time.

You could have a look at this implementation of a [concurrent linked hashmap](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/), I havnt use it so can't attest to it's features.

One thing to consider would be to switching from synchronized blocks to a ReadWriteLock to improve concurrent read only performance.

I'm not really sure of the utility of proving a remove at index method, perhaps you could give some more details about the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: linked hashmap does not give me improved indexing performance.

Comment: The class in OP keeps a collection of every object of a certain type reported over a socket connection. On the thread servicing the socket, the objects are passed to the addOrReplace method as the Value along with a Key object that is generated with the unique identifiers of Value. when an entry is added or changed, and event will be fired, and when an observer gets that event, it will refresh a UI (JTable, thus the indexing requirement) component by calling the getEntryAt(int) to draw it's values. Essentially the class above acts as a TableModel...

Comment: To be fair, you did answer my question about the synchronization...
Considering that the collection itself will only be *queried* on the EDT, I will have the worker thread that is making updates, submit the actual updates of the collection onto the EDT, by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() once the object has been parsed from the socket...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only care about finding values by index. If so, dump the Map and just use a List. Why do you need the Map?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `synchronized` and concurrent collections the way you have done it is not recommended. Any reason why you are maintaining two copies of the stuff you are interested in? You can easily get a list of all the keys from the map anytime rather than maintaining a separate list.

Comment: I want to index in constant time and lookup in constant time. 
list of keys
map of (key, values)

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the values in the list and in the map the key -> index mapping?

so for getEntry you only need on lookup (in the list which should be anyway faster than a map) and for remove you do not have to travers the whole list. Syhnronization happens so.

Comment: I should still have to synchronize the list though right? since it is being accessed by different threads.

Comment: btw, I did change my mapping per your suggestion, it does seem cleaner. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get all access to the List `keys` onto the event queue using `EventQueue.invokeLater`.  This will get rid of the synchronization.  With all the synching you were not running much in parallel anyway.  Also it means the `getSize` method will give the same answer for the duration of an event.

If you stick with synchronization instead of using `invokeLater`, at least get the `entries` hash table out of the synch block.  Either way, you get more parallel processing.  Of course, `entries` can now become out-of-synch with `keys`.  The only down side is sometimes a key will come up with a null entry.  With such a dynamic table this is unlikely to matter much.

Using the suggestion made by chrisichris to put the values in the list will solve this problem if it is one.  In fact, this puts a nice wall between `keys` and `entries`; they are now used in completely separate ways.  (If your only need for `entries` is to provide values to the JTable, you can get rid of it.)  But `entries` (if still needed) should reference the entries, not contain an index; maintaining indexes there would be a hopeless task.  And always remember that `keys` and `entries` are snapshots of "reality" (for lack of a better word) taken at different times.

Comment: I have moved all modification/reading to the EDT, i think this makes the most sense in this case.
If entries were pairs of (key, values) while the List contained values, I'd have to iterate the list to find which index needs a replaced reference in 'addOrReplace' if the '(key, value)' pair is already present. but if entries is pairs of (key, int) I can index the list's element and replace it's reference in constant time.